# Single Sign on between Joomla and Php

Tags: php, joomla1.5, xml-rpc, single-sign-on

I have two sites having different database first site is in joomla name suppose www.abc.com second is job portal written in Php run as www.abc.com/jobs.  I want to do single sign on for both . How i do that any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an LDAP Database as the primary storage for both your Joomla & Job portal site and the

LDAP Directory - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/13128

Can help you manage the clients with Joomla however depending on the platform of your portal the integration would have to be custom written but this should be a good starting point.